# Azure Data Factory - How to find total count of objects with more than 1 files with same "prefix" in an ADF expression?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Let's say have bunch of random sample files in a Blob which I want to copy into datalake as .parquet using ADF copy.

abc.1.txt,
abc.2.txt,
abc.3.txt,
def.1.txt,
ghi.1.txt,
xyz.1.txt,
xyz.2.txt

All abc & xyz object files should be merged/appended into their respective single .parquet file and remaining def, ghi as its individual .parquet file in data lake.

Need the output something like:

```
[
 {
   name: abc
   count: 3
 },
   name: def
   count: 1
 },
   name: ghi
   count: 1
 },
   name: xyz
   count: 2
 }
```

]

Pipeline flow would look something similar:

```
GetMetadata -->Filter if only 1 file -->Run ForEach file -->Copy activity(without merge)

GetMetadata -->SetVariable-->Filter if >1 file -->Run ForEach file -->Copy (with merge)
```

However, how do I get the count() of total files with same prefix in the Filter activity ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick thought,

You could get the file details in get meta data activity and push that to a SQL table and do a group by there and return count.

And loop over the result set in foreach and use if condition to check the count.

Here is what I'm doing.
[image: Pipeline]

My data lake:

[image: ADLS]

1. Firstly, get the childitems in getmetadata.
2. I'm then writing it to a string variable (optional)
3. From the string variable write to a text file
   [image: Source has one additional col-meta]
4. From the text file to Azure SQL server table.
5. Use the below query in the script activity

> select count(1), fileprefix from( select
> substring(name,0,charindex('.',name)-1) fileprefix,type from
> [dbo].[temptest] CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json) WITH(
> name varchar(200)
> , type varchar(60)
> ) as my_json_array)a group by fileprefix

My script output:
[image: Output]

Thanks.

Comment: This definitely is one way to do it. However, I was looking for within ADF expression itself using XML/XPath to do a GroupBy & count() for each item name, something like :- @string(xpath(xml(json(variables('var2'))), 'for $obj in /root/childItems
return count(/root/childItems/[name=$obj])')). However, this fails with an error:- The function 'xpath' parameters are invalid: the 'xpath' parameter must be a supported, well formed XPath expression. So not sure if this is the right way to do aggregation/groupby in Xpath.

Comment: Even this XML/Xpath expression also fails with same error:- @string(xpath(xml(json(variables('var2'))), 'count(for $obj in /root/childItems/name return $obj)'))